# Disallow line break in \cite

Tags: bibtex, line-breaking, citing

How can I disallow line break in `\cite`?

Two `bibtex` entries are

```
 @book{is,
        author    = "Mörður Árnason",
        title     = "Íslensk orðabók",
        publisher = "Edda",
        address  = "Reykjavík",
        year      = 2005}

@book{is13,
    author    = "Kristján Árnason",
    title     = "Íslensk tunga I. - Hljóð",
    publisher = "Almenna bókafélagið",
    address  = "Reykjavík",
    year      = 2005}
```

and unfortunately in text appears

```
... (M. % end of line
% new line
Árnason 2005) ...
```

Comment: that's odd I'd have expected your bibtex style to stop that, but `\mbox{\cite{is}}` will stop line breaking (but may also affect the size of word spaces, so isn't ideal)

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem, fortunately the spacing is ok.

Comment: You should add a MWE to your question; the suggested workaround may suffice, but with more details people may be able to suggest better remedies. For instance, few bibliography styles add the author's initial in author-year citations.

Comment: There is second author with the same surname. I have added this entry to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd have expected your bibtex style to stop that, but `\mbox{\cite{is}}` will stop line breaking (but may also affect the size of word spaces, so isn't ideal).