# How to prevent from line breaking in \cite?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have multiple `\cite{ref1, ref2,..}` commands in my document and I spotted that in some places LaTeX put a line break or even a page break.
See the attached image.
I am using `biblatex` package to handle the bibliography.
Is there any option to solve this issue in the whole book? Without playing with `\mbox{\cite{ref1...}}` ([Disallow line break in \cite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287739/disallow-line-break-in-cite)).

[image]

**Edit 24.10.2017**

It is hard to give running MWE. However, I use `biblatex`

```
\usepackage[
hyperref=auto,
mincrossrefs=999,
backend=biber,
style=numeric-comp,
sorting=none,
sortcites=true,
natbib=true,
urldate=short,
giveninits=true
]{biblatex}
```

so I cannot use package `cite`.

Comment: It should be possible to do that, but that depends very much on the style you use. Please prepare an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEb](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that reproduces the issue (or at least shows which style you use). What if there is a page number in the brackets ([1, p. 145]) would a break be allowed then?

Comment: Please tell us (a) which bibiography style you use and (b) which citation management package -- `cite`, `natbib`, etc. -- you employ.

Comment: Any news here? We really need to know what style you use. And an MWE helps us to get started more quickly and makes sure our solutions work for you.

Answer (score 7):

If your citations have no extra annotations then you can just use

```
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\nobreakspace}
```

replacing the `numeric-comp.cbx` definition which is `\addcomma\space`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
hyperref=auto,
mincrossrefs=999,
backend=biber,
style=numeric-comp,
sorting=none,
sortcites=true,
natbib=true,
urldate=short,
giveninits=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\parbox{4em}{The \cite{westfahl:space,angenendt} test.}

\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\nobreakspace}<
\parbox{4em}{The \cite{westfahl:space,angenendt} test.}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing this solution. Works great for me so far.