# Avoid line break when using \cite{} and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing, line-breaking

How can I enforce latex not to make line breaks of this form?

Assume, this code

```
First line~\cite{ref13,ref14,ref15,ref16,ref17}. Second line.
```

Produces the following output (line break because of the end of the line):

First line [13-
17]. Second line

While I would like to enforce smth like this:

First
line [13-17].
Second line

I'm using biblatex. But I would also be interested to know the answer for the case of using the standard latex bibliography.

**UPDATE**

A brute-force solution, thanks to @koleygr:

```
 \newcommand{\mcite}[1]{\mbox{\cite{#1}}}
```

Comment: I suppose you can use a command like `\mbox{\cite{Args}}` But since you didn't gave a MWE I haven't tested that and havent seen such a problem neither...

Comment: Thanks, this does the job. I'm surprised if this is not implemented as a standard feature in biblatex.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396778/how-to-prevent-from-line-breaking-in-cite?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks. Not sure, if it solves the problem in the case when the citation contains dashes, and works for both biblatex and standard bibliography cases.

Comment: How can `\cite{ref13-ref17}` even work? `biblatex` will treat this as a single entry.

Comment: I think with your last edit this becomes an exact duplicate mentioned by @TorbjørnT.

Comment: @DavidPurton Since the OP seems to use a `-comp` style, Andrew's answer can't really be applied in situation where one gets '13-17'. `biblatex` prints `\bibrangedash` there, so your `\renewrobustcmd*{\bibrangedash}{\textendash}` should do the right thing here. Consider undeleting your answer.

Comment: @mavzolej You can avoid leaving people guessing what exactly you want if you post a proper [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)s instead of just a short code snippet. That way people can see exactly what you are talking about and can test their solutions.

Comment: @moewe, good call! I missed that. I'll fix it tomorrow. Can't undelete from phone.

Comment: @moewe, I undeleted and added a more specific answer for the question.

Answer (score 2):

## Update

With new info in the question, this seems like a good answer for `biblatex`. For standard bibliographies, you would need to alter the relevant `bst` file to replace the `--` with `\textendash`, but this is always a pain.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \renewrobustcmd*{\bibrangedash}{\textendash}
}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\parbox{3.8cm}{%
\begin{sloppypar}
Filler text filler text \cite{baez/article,bertram,doody,gillies}.
\end{sloppypar}

\noindent\textbf{cf.\@ default behaviour}

Filler text filler text [1--4].}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Your question is a little unclear, but I assume you are referring to page ranges?

Both `-` and `--` contain (I think) an implied `\penalty\hyphenpenalty` after them, so they will break as you are seeing.

With default settings for both standard bibliographies and `biblatex`, you could use `\cite[13\textendash 17]{entry}`, which won't break.

If I where using `biblatex` I'd use `\mkcomprange` (see Table 13 in the manual for set up) and ensure `\bibrangedash` is not breakable (by default in English it is defined as `\textendash\penalty\hyphenpenalty`).

(**Note:** This doesn't seem to work with `xelatex` which allows a break after `\textendash`. Perhaps someone else can help with this case.)

Something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book,
  author = {Author},
  title = {Title}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\setcounter{mincompwidth}{1000}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \renewrobustcmd*{\bibrangedash}{\textendash}
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkcomprange[{\mkpageprefix[pagination]}]{#1}}
\begin{document}
\hsize 4cm

\begin{sloppypar}
\cite[13-17]{book}
\end{sloppypar}

\noindent
\textbf{cf.\@ default behaviour}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}
\cite[13--17]{book}

\noindent
\textbf{and with} \verb+\textendash+

\begin{sloppypar}
\cite[13\textendash 17]{book}
\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry! Someone has changed the code of my question and the meaning has been changed completely :( Please see now. The question is about the place in the text where the citation is appearing.

Comment: No worries! Actually, I can probably change my answer. I think you can probably still automate it without resorting to an mbox

Comment: Starting with `biblatex` 3.11 (as of now unreleased) `biblatex` will automatically normalise page ranges in the postnote. So the trick with using comp ranges and disabling the compression by modifying the counters won't be needed any more.